# Eloquent ORM: Similar queries with same variable

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Is there any possible way to retrieve the results of similar queries using Eloquent? Say you would like `first_column` to be the same value in three queries, but `second_column` to be three different values for those queries. 

**Example:**

```
$query = Model::where('first_column', '=', $something);

list($value, $diff_value, $another_diff_value) = [1, 2, 3];

// This is where I would like the results to diverge.
$one = $query->where('second_column', '=', $value)->get();
$two = $query->where('second_column', '=', $diff_value)->get();
$three = $query->where('second_column', '=', $another_diff_value)->get();
```

**Expected results:**

```
$one | first_column | second_column |    $two | first_column | second_column |    $three | first_column | second_column |
-----+--------------+---------------+   ------+--------------+---------------+   --------+--------------+---------------+
     |       1      |       1       |         |       1      |       2       |           |       1      |       3       |
     |--------------|---------------|         |--------------|---------------|           |--------------|---------------|
     |       1      |       1       |         |       1      |       2       |           |       1      |       3       |
     |--------------|---------------|         |--------------|---------------|           |--------------|---------------|
     |       1      |       1       |         |       1      |       2       |           |       1      |       3       |
     |--------------|---------------|         |--------------|---------------|           |--------------|---------------|
     |       1      |       1       |         |       1      |       2       |           |       1      |       3       |
     |--------------|---------------|         |--------------|---------------|           |--------------|---------------|
     |       1      |       1       |         |       1      |       2       |           |       1      |       3       |
     --------------------------------         --------------------------------           --------------------------------
```

**Actual results:**

```
$one | first_column | second_column |   $two | empty   $three | empty
-----+--------------+---------------+   
     |       1      |       1       |         
     |--------------|---------------|         
     |       1      |       1       |         
     |--------------|---------------|         
     |       1      |       1       |         
     |--------------|---------------|         
     |       1      |       1       |         
     |--------------|---------------|         
     |       1      |       1       |         
     --------------------------------
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. This can be done, but you need to clone `$query`. It also helps to use Laravel's `with` helper function for chaining:

```
$query = Model::where('first_column', '=', $something);

list($value, $diff_value, $another_diff_value) = [1, 2, 3];

// This is where I would like the results to diverge.
$one = with(clone($query))->where('second_column', '=', $value)->get();
$two = with(clone($query))->where('second_column', '=', $diff_value)->get();
$three = with(clone($query))->where('second_column', '=', $another_diff_value)->get();
```

It seems like this would be useful if `$query` is a longer query than the one provided in the example.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you need to finish the queries for each one. I know what you're trying to do, tried it myself - and it should work on paper. But it doesn't.

So just use 3 queries. No way around it.

```
$first = 'alwaysTheSame';
$second = [1,2,3];
$data1 = Model::where('first', '=', $first)->where('second', '=', $second[0])->get();
 $data2 = Model::where('first', '=', $first)->where('second', '=', $second[1])->get();
 $data3 = Model::where('first', '=', $first)->where('second', '=', $second[2])->get();
```

Happy coding!